# WPF Custom-Control Style Not Implemented

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I hope someone can help me please.

I am taking my first tentative steps into WPF by first making a simple custom control. The structure is indicated below.

[image]

And the respective code is
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPFCustomControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFCustomControl.NewFolder1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <local:MyCustomControl x:Name = "customControl"                                  
     Content = "Click Me" Width = "70" 
     Margin = "10" Click = "customControl_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Name = "txtBlock"  
     Width = "250" Height = "30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFCustomControl.NewFolder1">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}" BasedOn = "{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property = "Background" Value = "LightSalmon" />
    <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value = "Blue"/>
</Style>
```

Everything works as expected.
My issue is when I move the Themes folder into the NewFolder1 the application compiles but no Style is implemented.

Thank you in advance for any advice on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is when I move the Themes folder into the NewFolder1 the application compiles but no Style is implemented.

That's expected. The default style for the control should be located in `themes/generic.xaml`. This is by convention and where the framework will look for it.

You may move your `Style` to another `ResourceDictionary` in `NewFolder1` and then modify `themes/generic.xaml` to merge this one:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    ..>

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControl;component/NewFolder1/YourDictionary.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Or you could just define your custom `Style` directly in `themes/generic.xaml`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I was to create a control library with multiple controls in their separate folders, each with their own style ResorceDictionary. Would they all then need merging in to the Themes/Generic.xml?

Comment: @StephenH: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are doing following mistake,
go to App.xaml and add Styles as below example

```
<Application.Resources>
        <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="NewFolder1/Generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response however this doesn't appear to work for me. Everything compiles but I get blue line error under <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/>"Error occurred while finding the Resource Dictionary Themes/Generic.xaml". I am also curious as to why I didn't need to merge dictionary when the Themes Folder was outside NewFolder1 as the image above.

Comment: I should have said that I tried both <ResourceDictionary Source="NewFolder1/Generic.xaml"/> and <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/>. No of these works for me.

Comment: The solution was that I needed to include /Themes/ so that it read <ResourceDictionary Source="NewFolder1/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>. This does lead me to another question however. If I was creating a control library with multiple folders each with there own independent Theme Folders would these all need merging despite the fact that they were only used by the specific control in there folder? I have included an image above to try and indicate what I mean.