# WPF BasedOn is null during runtime but works in designer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a custom WPF control called Heading that I am styling application-wide using Theme.xaml, where I set a ControlTemplate. I'm tweaking this style for certain windows using BasedOn. This works in the designer but fails during runtime. The result is an invisible control because it has no control template.

This happens for multiple custom controls in this project. Those controls work fine in other projects.

The style in Theme.xaml:

```xml
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls3:Heading}">
     <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls3:Heading}">
                 <StackPanel>
                     <Grid>
                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                    FontWeight="Bold" 
                                    FontSize="12" LineHeight="12"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                                    Foreground="{StaticResource SolidWorksTextGrayBrush}"/>

                         <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                                 ToolTip="{TemplateBinding Button1Tooltip}"
                                 Width="25" Height="25" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                 Command="{TemplateBinding Button1Command}"
                                 Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowButton1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                 Focusable="False">
                             <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Button1ImageSource}"
                                    Width="{TemplateBinding Button1ImageWidth}"/>
                         </Button>
                         <Button Grid.Column="2" 
                                 ToolTip="{TemplateBinding Button2Tooltip}"
                                 Width="25" Height="25" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                 Command="{TemplateBinding Button2Command}"
                                 Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowButton2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                 Focusable="False">
                             <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Button2ImageSource}"
                                    Width="{TemplateBinding Button2ImageWidth}"/>
                         </Button>
                     </Grid>
                 </StackPanel>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

The styling in the window:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ProjectName.Addin;component/Windows/Theme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="controls:Heading" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:Heading}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 10 0 5" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I've done a lot of debugging and noticed:

1. When I set a breakpoint in code-behind, the BasedOn property is null even though I set this property.
2. The style works when I give it a key and add that key every time I create a Heading.
3. The style works when I comment+uncomment it and hot-reload is enabled. So it feels like the style is not present when BasedOn is first set.
4. The style works when I create the style in code in the code-behind.
5. I use multiple styles and custom controls and this project has more problems than all other projects. So this feels like a project-wide issue, but I can't find the difference between the projects.

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Some background info: this is a WPF library that contains a plugin for SolidWorks. Since it's a library, there is no App.xaml for application-wide resources since there is no application.

Comment: Merge this in app.xaml Source="/ProjectName.Addin;component/Windows/Theme.xaml

Comment: @Andy The theme is a base style that I derive a style from for this window. Windows often need a slightly different styling, which is what the BasedOn property is for. So merging the styles isn't solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default style for a custom control should by convention be defined in a resource dictionary named `themes/generic.xaml`. That's where WPF will look for it by default.

So create a `themes` folder at the root of the project, move your resource dictionary into this folder, rename it to `generic.xaml`, and remove the stuff you have inside `<Window.Resources>`.

- [What is so special about Generic.xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228875/what-is-so-special-about-generic-xaml)
- [WPF Custom-Control Style Not Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465822/wpf-custom-control-style-not-implemented)

Comment: I had already tried this and it didn't make a difference. But I tried again. I did get an error message saying that the Themes folder already existed (it didn't), maybe that's a hint. I was able to add the folder to the csproj file manually. Since this is a WPF library, there is no App.xaml so there are no application-wide resources. I think I will always need to add the merged dictionaries to each window because the styling was not applied automatically.

Comment: *I did get an error message saying that the Themes folder already existed (it didn't)* What? And of course it makes a difference whether you actually located the default style where it's looked up by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

The error could be in several places. I’ll show you all the important points here.

1. The default style key must be overridden in the static constructor. For an element type, it is set equal to the element type itself. Therefore, it is specified twice in the OverrideMetadata method: as the first method parameter, and as the first property metadata parameter.

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Core2023
{
    public class SomeCustomControl : Control
    {
        static SomeCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(SomeCustomControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SomeCustomControl)));
        }
    }
}
```

2. The default style (including the element template) must be specified in the resource dictionary in the Themes folder in the same assembly in which the Custom Control is declared. The name of the dictionary must correspond to the theme (Windows) in which it will be used. The default style key is set to the element type for which it is intended. The common dictionary for all topics is called General.
   Starting template for `Themes/General.xaml`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeCustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeCustomControl}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

3. If the application needs to override the default style (usually this is done in App resources), then you also need to set the style with a key equal to the element type. In this case, a derived style with BaseOn equal to a static resource with an element type key will return the style specified in the application.
   But to get the base style from the theme, you DO NOT need to set the BaseOn property.
4. If the application does not override the default style, then the style without BaseOn and the style with BaseOn equal to the type will be inherited from the theme style.

```xml
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeCustomControl}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.SomeCCStyleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SomeCCStyleWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <UniformGrid>
        <local:SomeCustomControl/>
        <local:SomeCustomControl>
            <FrameworkElement.Style>
                <Style/>
            </FrameworkElement.Style>
        </local:SomeCustomControl>
        <local:SomeCustomControl>
            <FrameworkElement.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:SomeCustomControl}}"
                       TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeCustomControl}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                </Style>
            </FrameworkElement.Style>
        </local:SomeCustomControl>
        <local:SomeCustomControl>
            <FrameworkElement.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeCustomControl}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                </Style>
            </FrameworkElement.Style>
        </local:SomeCustomControl>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try override the defaultstylekey in the custom control constructor like this:

```
public class Heading
{
    static Heading()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Heading),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Heading)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have that. I just did a diff between your code and mine and they are identical :)

Comment: try remove this         

<Style TargetType="controls:Heading" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:Heading}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 10 0 5" />
        </Style>

i.e just use the defined style in themes.xaml. (If you want these margins, either define it in the style, or if its dependant on something, then set the Margin in the style using a DynamicResource

Comment: That works, but it makes the whole BasedOn cascading styles useless. It works fine in other projects, so it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you are doing it wrong, you need to define your style using a key "HeadingBaseStyle". then under it you define a new style based on the key targeting  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource HeadingBaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type controls3:Heading}"/> only

then in your window you base it on the style using the key "HeadingBaseStyle"

voila, not useless

Comment: Thanks for your help, truly. Not adding a key is not wrong. If you don't add a key, the style is applied to all elements of that type. They call it 'implicit' in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-style. In my other apps, "BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls3:Heading}}""  works fine.

Comment: i think it flew over you, read and take it in